# Nifi Email ConsumeIMAP filter by subject, from , to and date

Tags: email, apache-nifi

Using ConsumeIMAP to read emails from an Inbox and trying to select only emails that have
- attachment to download 
- sent "From" xyz@yahoo.com 
- send "To" abc@gmail.com
- Have "Daily" in their subject 
- at 8 am EST

Please let me know if it can be set in any component. I tried to use EvaluateJsonPath, ExtractEmailHeaders and RouteonAttribute but no luck yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have been exploring the correct path. You should be able to achieve this using a flow consisting of:

```
ConsumeIMAP >> ExtractEmailHeaders >> RouteOnAttribute
```

[`ConsumeIMAP`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-email-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.email.ConsumeIMAP/) will download messages from the email server and create a single FlowFile for each message, storing the email message raw bytes in the FlowFile contents.

[`ExtractEmailHeaders`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-email-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.email.ExtractEmailHeaders/) attempts to parse a FlowFile's contents as email (must be [RFC-2822 compliant](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt)), extract email headers, and write each header field to a FlowFile attribute, including:

- email.headers.from.*
- email.headers.to.*
- email.headers.subject
- email.headers.sent_date

Note that `ExtractEmailHeaders` is not doing any filtering, just populating FlowFile attributes based on the FlowFile content, thus making the FlowFiles more easily routable downstream in the flow. Start just by creating a flow that has these two processors and verify that the output of the `ExtractEmailHeaders` processor meets these expectations. If not, its possible the email messages are malformed or not RFC-2822 compliant.

After you have successfully sent email FlowFiles through `ExtractEmailHeaders`, you can do the filtering using one or more [`RouteOnAttribute`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.RouteOnAttribute/) processors using the [NiFi Expression Language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html) to define your match conditions, e.g.:

```
${email.headers.subject.contains("Daily")}
```

If you have verified that your flow is working correctly through `ExtractEmailHeaders`, but the filtering in `RouteOnAttribute` is not working as expected, make sure your attribute expressions and assumptions about email header values (e.g., capitalization, datetime format) are correct. Consult the [Apache NiFi Expression Language Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html) and if you have specific questions relating to the expression language itself, search here or post another question on that specifically.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Kevdoran.It seems something is still not right as I get this error  in ExtractEmailHeaders : 22:05:13 EDTERROR293bf92b-015e-1000-039b-f24fa5408f90
ExtractEmailHeaders[id=293bf92b-015e-1000-039b-f24fa5408f90] Could not parse the flowfile StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=28bdfc5d-7a7e-4428-8851-965815ca95c6,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1503942358650-1, container=default, section=1], offset=2794780, length=16168],offset=0,name=384325527525072,size=16168] as an email, treating as failure: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Is the FlowFile content a [RFC-2822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) compliant format?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be RFC 2822 compliant as per the url below 
   https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.6

Comment: Also, even if it were to work, it would be in efficient for NiFi to go over each email, extract header and then route the email. I wish the ConsumeIMAP/POP3 had a way to filter emails while reading and generating flowfiles for the filtered emails only.

Comment: Are you able to post the full stack trace for the NullPointerException? Regarding efficiency, I think NiFi will be able to handle the load fine unless it is a very busy inbox. How do you expect to read the headers without downloading the email message content? The reading of the headers once downloaded should be low overhead, and then the flow files that don't match will be discarded. It is common in NiFi for each processor to do a very tiny amount of work.

Comment: That said, if you really wanted to avoid this approach of doing the filtering in NiFi, you could apply rules in your email server to fwd messages that have the condition you want to a separate inbox (assuming your email server supports such operations) and point NiFi ConsumeIMAP to read all emails from the new inbox. That seems brittle as you now have part of your data flow outside of NiFi which is less ideal. If you are comfortable programming in Java you could also write a custom processor based on ConsumeIMAP or ConsumePOP3 with your filtering logic added.

Comment: 2017-08-30 16:36:05,930 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-8] o.a.n.p.email.ExtractEmailHeaders ExtractEmailHeaders[id=293bf92b-015e-1000-039b-f24fa5408f90] Could not parse the flowfile StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=bff197e1-d9b9-4289-abfb-5a31a0f7096b,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1504125365849-1, container=default, section=1], offset=0, length=7812],offset=0,name=398333274170241,size=7812] as an email, treating as failure: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(Native Method)
 at org.apache.nifi.processors.email.ExtractEmailHeaders$1.process(ExtractEmailHeaders.java:171)
 at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.read(StandardProcessSession.java:2177)
 at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.read(StandardProcessSession.java:2147)
 at org.apache.nifi.processors.email.ExtractEmailHeaders.onTrigger(ExtractEmailHeaders.java:146)
 at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)

Comment: at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1118)
 at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:147)
 at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47)
 at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:132)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)

Comment: Looking through the source code based on that stack trace, the method that is returning null is from the email parsing library when it is trying to extract recipients. The method states:

Comment: `Get all the recipient addresses for the message. The default implementation extracts the TO, CC, and BCC recipients ... This method returns null if none of the recipient headers are present in this message.`

Comment: This part of the code is past the RFC-2822 check, so you are correct it is a well-formed email message. But an assumption in this part of the code appears to be that at least one of TO, CC, or BCC will be set. It appears in your case, NiFi encountered a message in that inbox that does not have a TO, CC, or BCC set. Can you check if that possible? We should open a JIRA ticket for the NiFi project to added a check for null here.

Comment: You're right.It is an auto email from client to their own inbox and does not have "to", "cc"and "bcc" so can we open a JIRA ticket and once the logic has been changed, what steps/Git command should I take to get the latest change?Thanks, Kevdoran

Comment: I created a [NiFi JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4339) and started a [bugfix branch on my github](https://github.com/kevdoran/nifi/tree/NIFI-4339). If you are comfortable building NiFi from source, you can clone my repository, checkout the NiFi-4339 branch, and run a mvn build there which will have the fix. If you create a ASF JIRA account, you can "watch" the ticket to get notified of progress, such as when it is included in a stable NiFi release. It would be great if you could test the fix as well to make sure it solves your problem!

Comment: Additionally, because this is in an extension, we should be able to build a NAR (NiFi Archive) bundle just for the patched ExtractEmailHeaders processor that you could add, like a plugin, to any NiFi release, which could get you by until the next NiFi release that includes this patch. The next planned NiFi release is 1.4.0, which is going to start soon according to the NiFi dev email list. This is a pretty small bug so it might make it into that release, if not probably the one after that.

Comment: Thank you, Kevdoran. I wish any command( MAC/Linux) that you could share to get only the part that has been changed in this processor or update the whole processor. As  I don't know how to do NAR bundle and the 1st solution to do Git clone will make me lose my work/settings so far.Either way I really appreciate all your help so far.

Comment: Sure, it's pretty straightforward. Your NiFi home directory (where /bin and /conf are located should have a /lib directory. In that directory are all the NAR bundles that get loaded at launch time. The one you need to update is `nifi-email-nar-{version}.nar`. To build the NAR based on my branch, you want to follow [these instructions for building from source](https://nifi.apache.org/quickstart.html) in order to install all the dependencies (JDK 1.8, Maven, etc). Then run this command:

Comment: `git clone git@github.com:kevdoran/nifi.git && cd nifi && git checkout NIFI-4339 && mvn -T C2.0 clean install && echo -n "NAR Location: " && find ./nifi-nar-bundles -name "nifi-email-nar-*.nar"`

Comment: That will build NiFi from source and output the location of the NAR file you want. Copy that to your NiFi Home /lib directory and restart NiFi. I would make a copy/backup of the existing `nifi-email-nar` bundle in a safe location first in case you need to restore it if this does not work. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a Ton, Kevdoran. Thats a big help!

Comment: Hi @Kevdoran, I tried the command above and get access error :                   Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.253.112' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: First, you will need to [create a github account](https://github.com/) if you do not already have one. Then, try the command again, but replace `git@github.com:kevdoran/nifi.git` with `https://github.com/kevdoran/nifi.git`, which will prompt you for your github username and password. For more information about cloning via ssh (the original URI I provided) vs. https (the replacement URI), see [Github's documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/). Also, I'm working with the NiFi community to try to get this fix finalized and included with v1.4.0 or v1.4.1.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it!

Comment: @Hem - A [patch with the fix](https://github.com/apache/nifi/pull/2111) was merged to apache-nifi/master, as tracked in ASF JIRA issue [NIFI-4326](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4326). This will be included in the next stable NiFi release, planned to be 1.4.0 which should be out sometime in the next week or two judging from discussion on the Apache NiFi mailing list. Thanks again for help uncovering the issue and verifying the fix!

Comment: How to get body of the email?

Comment: @vishal you should probably post a new question rather than continuing this thread

Comment: @kevdoran fair enough.

Comment: with nifi v1.11.1 you need to set this expression (with `:` ) `${email.headers.subject.contains("Daily")}` otherwise you will get a parsing error